# nyc code coverage not working for NodeJs express server

Tags: node.js, express, code-coverage, istanbul, nyc

I have a NodeJs express server named `app.js`, I want to do a code coverage using `nyc`.

```
// app.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send({
    message: 'Hello World!'
  })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

```
//.nycrc.json
{
  "all": true,
  "cache": false,
  "check-coverage": true,
  "sourceMap": false,
  "instrument": false,
  "cmd": "./",
  "temp-dir": "./.nyc_output",
  "include": [
    "e2e-app/src/**/*.ts",
    "server/app.js"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "e2e-app/src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "report-dir": "./coverage-e2e",
  "reporter": [
    "lcov",
    "text",
    "text-summary",
    "cobertura"
  ],
  "branches": 80,
  "lines": 80,
  "functions": 80,
  "statements": 80,
  "watermarks": {
    "statements": [
      70,
      100
    ],
    "branches": [
      70,
      100
    ],
    "functions": [
      70,
      100
    ],
    "lines": [
      70,
      100
    ]
  }
}
```

1. In terminal I do `nyc node server/app.js`
2. In my browser, I go to `http://localhost:3000`, I see the `Hello World!` printed on my screen.
3. I see there is a folder `.nyc_output` created with a `json` file, but the json's content is just an empty object.
4. I kill NodeJs process, and run `nyc report`, I got an empty report.

What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Are you using an [.nycrc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc) file? Have you tried with `nyc --reporter=lcov`?

Comment: @Pieterjan I updated the question with `.nycrc.json`, I tried to use `nyc --reporter-lcov`, the report is still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is do this
`node node_module/nyc/bin/nyc npm start`